# How to run code on login in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, authentication, events, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to run a function every time a user logs in. What I tried is to obtain an instance of `AuthenticationStateProvider` from the DI container and subscribe to its `AuthenticationStateChanged` event. The problem is that my login pages are implemented using server-rendered Razor Pages so the page refreshes after a successful login. This means that my code subscribes to the event after it is fired, so my handler function never runs. Can anybody see a way to run custom code upon successful login?

Comment: Not me...It's probably sb. disappointed with your question, perhaps because she can't answer it. Anyhow, If you're using the token based authentication (API), you can attach an event handler to the RemoteAuthenticatorView component located in the Authentication component. I think it has an event that is invoked immediately after a user log in. As far as I recall, I've once answered a similar question that way, and then changed my answer to something more useful. Try this solution, and let us know if it's OK.

Comment: Up-voted your answer...

Comment: @enet Thank you! that is exactly what I was looking for. If you'll post it as an answer I'll accept it (if you want the reputation points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the token based authentication (API), you can attach an event handler to the RemoteAuthenticatorView component located in the Authentication component. I think it has an event that is invoked immediately after a user log in. As far as I recall, I've once answered a similar question that way, and then changed my answer to something more useful. Try this solution, and let us know if it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `AuthorizationService` into your component and then await the `AuthenticationState` to run code if your user is logged in. Further details are in the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#procedural-logic).

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

<button @onclick="@DoSomething">Do something important</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private async Task DoSomething()
    {
        var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Perform an action only available to authenticated (signed-in) users.
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of an onclick handler you can put the auth check in a component's initializedasync method or wherever else is appropriate.

Another approach is to hook into the `OnLoginSucceeded` property of the `RemoteAuthenticatorView`, like:

```
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="OnLoginSucceeded" />
@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }

    private void OnLoginSucceeded() 
    {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: But then my code will run every time the component is rendered. I'd like the authentication action to trigger a function just once

Comment: Then you can put it in a component that only gets rendered once (like your main layout or similar) or use some application state to keep track of whether you've triggered the function already.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to run code just once in Blazor...the best we can do is once per page refresh. Using persistent storage is an option, but I think there should be a better way to subscribe to a simple event... The provider knows when there is a change and it triggers an event, I just can figure out how to subscribe to it.

Comment: There's no direct "event" to subscribe to, in the sense that this code will be running in the browser while the authentication itself is happening on the server, a completely different machine. As @enet has mentioned, the client's [RemoteAuthenticatorView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.remoteauthenticatorview?view=aspnetcore-5.0) has a property called `OnLoginSucceeded` that may be what you want.